# Designing a common-emitter amplifier circuit

Tags: amplifier, design, bjt

We are asked to design values for `RC, RE, R1, and R2` for the following common-emitter BJT amplifier:

[image]

It's easy to calculate RE and RC:

[image]

But I couldn't find a way to design values for R1 and R2. **So how can I do that?**

Comment: Rule of thumb I(B) is < 10% of the current through R1 and R2. Also C1/R1/R2 does influence the lower frequency response. On a side note, R(L) is not given but it does influence voltage gain.

Answer (score 1):

As its most likely a homework/class problem I'll take you through the process and let you finish it off.

For a silicon transistor the base voltage (Vb) will be about 0.6V higher than the emitter so if you know (or set) Ve you can write down Vb.

The gain of a small signal transistor will be at least 100 so if we take the current flowing through R1 and R2 as about 1/10th the collector (or emitter) current, When the potential divider (R1,R2) is connected to the transistor base the current taken by the base, Ib, will not significantly affect the 'calculated' voltage at the junction. By your calculation this will be about 0.1mA.

You can use Ohm's law to calculate the total resistance of R1 and R2  (= Vcc / 0.1mA = 15 * 10^3/ 0.1) = 150000 or 150k

Last part of the puzzle   R2/(R1+R2) * 15 = 1.6  (voltage divider equation)

As you already know (R1+R2 = 150k) the only unknown is R2

Once you calculate R2 then R1 is easy to find.

Finally, you should check your answers for nearest preferred values (say E24 series ). Instead of 0.995k use a 1k0 (npv).

Comment: R1 and R2 does not affect the small signal gain, right? What is the reason of choosing the current through R1 and R2 to be (1/10)Ic ??

Comment: @ammarx R1,R2 set up the DC bias condition so what we aim for is a voltage at their junction which is about 0.6V/0.7V higher than the voltage we need at the emitter. When you calculate this voltage you don't consider any current being drawn into the base. When the base is connected it will slightly lower this voltage. By choosing R1,R2 current as 1/10th Ic then even if the BJT has a (min) gain of about 100 there is at least 10x more current through these resistors than is drawn into the base. This keeps the voltage drop within 10% of the calculated value. Near enough for practical circuits.

Comment: Ok, I followed your instructions and got values for R1 and R2 (R1 = 133k and R2 = 17k), but sorry I still don't understand why the current is chosen this way. What is the relation between this and the required gain?. Can you make it simpler. Thanks.

Comment: @ammarx Its because we can't put precise figures to BJT gains (hfe etc.) - any given device will have a wide range of values so a precise calculation would have no real meaning. We use this 'rule of thumb' type calculation because it gives us a sensible (ball park) answer that works. Remember that although you can calculate a resistance value to any number of decimal points real world resistors come in preferred value packages. http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/emitter-resistance.html